# Problem rendering an Ajax partial with link_to specifying a controller action

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, partial, link-to

I have a div (id="content") on a "proposition" show page into which I want to render different partials depending on which tab at the top of the div is selected.

I'm trying to render a partial (substantive_content) with AJAX using the following link_to:

```
<%= link_to "Connected", :url => {:controller => "propositions", 
                           :action => "substantive_content"}, :remote => true %>
```

I've got two problems:

1. On clicking the link, a GET request
   is sent to
   `PropositionsController#show`, and
   not (I presume) to the "substantive
   content" action. This just refreshes the page and doesn't do anything remotely. The correct partial isn't displayed.
2. I'm not sure how then to render a
   partial into the "content" div.

At the moment I have this in the PropositionsController:

```
  def substantive_content
     respond_to do |format|
         format.js{ render :update do |rightbar|
                 rightbar.replace_html 'content', 'Hello World!'
         end}
     end
  end
```

... but am not sure where to go from here. Am I even going about this in the right way? I'm very new to rails, javascript, etc.

Any help with either of these problems would be fantastic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes.rb file you should have an entry for the substantive_content action.  It might look something like this:

```
match "substantive_content" => "propositions#substantive_content", :as => substantive_content
```

Then in your view the link should look something like this:

```
<%= link_to "Connected", substantive_content_path, :remote => true %>
```

I would render a js.erb file when the js request comes to the substantive_content action.  The action would look soemthing like this:

```
def substantive_content
  respond_to do |format|               
    format.js
  end        
end
```

Then create a substantive_content.js.erb file in your views/propositions directory.  In that file you can use jquery to update the content div:

```
$('#content').html("<%= render :partial => 'your_partial_name_here' %>");
```

Without knowing more about the actual application you're working on, its hard to say if this is the best way to accomplish what you want.  I generally try to stay as "RESTful" as possible with my apps so I'm reluctant to create actions aren't part of the normal index, new, create, show, etc. set.  That's not to say that it isn't neccesary in this case, but it's something to think about.

Comment: Thanks dbp - that's great. For some reason it wouldn't work with :as => substantive_content on the end of the route. Having removed that, it's working perfectly.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that this method doesn't respect much the frontend-backend separation paradigm. Backend (RoR) should return a JSON object with the info that then should be rendered by frontend with JS. This way needs 2 different partial files to do one simple thing.